# Вывод коллекции

Tags: c#, массивы, коллекции, список

Есть массив и список такого же типа. В цикле я изменяю массив и после каждого изменения добавляю его в список (по окончанию цикла хочу получить список из всех массивов которые получились в результате изменений). Но при выводе списка все его элементы одинаковы, аналогичны последнему добавленному в список массиву. Почему это происходит?

```
        byte[,] mat = new byte[3, 3];
        List<byte[,]> list = new List<byte[,]>();

        for (int m = 0; m < 9; ++m)
        {
            byte i = 0;
            byte j = 0;

            // Поиск пустой ячейки (нулевой)
            bool flag = false;
            for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
                    if (mat[i, j] == 0)
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                if (flag) break;
            }

            // Добавление измененного массива в список
            mat[i, j] = 1;
            list.Add(mat);

            // Вывод всех элементов списка
            foreach (byte[,] a in list)
            {
                PrintMatrix(a);
            }
        }


    private void PrintMatrix(byte[,] mat)
    {
        bool inLine = false; // Вывод в строку или квадратом

        for (byte i = 0; i < mat.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (byte j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0,2}", mat[i, j]); 
            }
            if (inLine) Console.Write("   ");
            else Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: а как работает `PrintMatrix`?

Comment: @Vardan Vardanyan, это просто функция для вывода матрицы в консоль красиво. Работает перебором при помощи двух циклов

Comment: добавь код как то мне так не кажется

Comment: добавил, но там всё рабочее

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все дело в том, что *массивы - это [ссылочный тип данных](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx)*.

 Вот что это значит в контексте вашей задачи: ваш список состоит не из 
 одинаковых объектов, а из одного объекта. Как так получилось? Ответ :

1. Вы присвоили ссылке mat объект
2. Изменили объект на который указывает ссылка mat
3. Добавили ссылку на этот объект в список
4. изменили объект на который указывает ссылка mat, то есть вы изменили тот объект который был уже добавлен в коллекцию
5. Добавили ссылку на этот объект в список(на тот самый многострадальный объект)

   После выполнения этих действий мы имеем что mat, list[0], list[1] указывают на один и тот же объект в управляемой куче.
   Для решения проблемы достаточно заменить `list.Add(mat);` на `list.Add((byte[,])mat.Clone());` но такое решение можно использовать только с массивами типов значений.

Comment: Дело в том, что этот список мне нужен для отслеживания изменений которые происходили с массивом, поэтому создавать каждый раз новый массив не выход.

Comment: @zRirez увидел, видимо спать пора, проглядел часть логики в вашем коде.